# the issues of calling overridable methods from constructor

Tags: java, constructor, overriding

if it is possible please make this sentence clear for me

here, the author said:

> Do not call overridable methods from constructors. When creating a
>   subclass object, this could lead to an overridden method being called
>   before the subclass object is fully initialized. Recall that when you
>   construct a subclass object, its constructor first calls one of the
>   direct superclass’s constructors. **If the superclass constructor
>   calls an overridable method, the subclass’s version of that method
>   will be called by the superclass constructor**—before the subclass
>   constructor’s body has a chance to execute.

i can't understand that how it can be possible to call a subclass's version of the overridable method in the superclass's constructor

TnX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first make a distinction between instantiation and initialization. Instantiation is the process of creating an instance of a type (allocating the space for it and getting a reference to that space). Initialization is the process of setting the state of the instance to its initial value.

Take the following type hierarchy:

```
class Foo { 
    public Foo() {}
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    public Bar() {super();}
}
```

New instance creation expressions

```
new Bar();
```

cause instantiation and initialization. Instantiation happens first. Java creates an instance of concrete type `Bar`.

Then initialization needs to take place. In an inheritance hierarchy, the initialization follows the same hierarchy, but top to bottom.

```
Object
   |
  Foo 
   |
  Bar
```

The constructor for `Object` runs first to initialize the state that is defined as part of `Object`, then the constructor for `Foo` is run to initialize the state that is defined as part of `Foo` and finally the constructor for `Bar` is run to initialize the state defined in `Bar`. **Your instance is still of type `Bar`.** So polymorphism still applies. If you invoke an instance method and that method is overriden somewhere lower in the hierarchy, that implementation will be invoked.

That's what that quote is referring to. It's dangerous. Read more here:

[What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors)

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the reason this is a bad idea with some (simplistic) code, consider these two classes:

```
class Greeter {
    protected Greeter() {
        printHello();
    }

    protected void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Looks simple enough, it prints `Hello` whenever you instantiate it.  Now lets extend it:

```
class NamedGreeter extends Greeter {
    private String name;

    public NamedGreeter(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

The intent is clearly to have the `NamedGreeter` greet you by name when instantiated, but in fact it will always print `Hello null` because the super constructor is called first when the `NamedGreeter` is instantiated.

Thanks to how polymorphism works, any time the `printHello()` method is called on a `NamedGreeter` (even if that call is from within the `Greeter` class) the implementation in `NamedGreeter` will be called.  Calling that method from within the constructor of the parent class means that even if the child class extends it then no fields defined by the child will be initialized, simply because it's not possible to do anything in the child constructor (like initialize fields) before the parent constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

An example demonstrating that the child method will be invoked:

```
class Foo {
  static class Parent {
    Parent() {
      someMethod();
    }
    void someMethod() {}
  }

  static class Child extends Parent {
    @Override void someMethod() {
      throw new AssertionError("Invoked");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Child();  // Throws Exception.
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Invoked
        at Foo$Child.someMethod(Foo.java:16)
        at Foo$Parent.<init>(Foo.java:9)
        at Foo$Child.<init>(Foo.java:14)
        at Foo.main(Foo.java:21)
```